# Comparar 2 listas y obtener los valores diferenter C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, lista, foreach

tengo una clase llamada tabla

```
    public class tabla 
    {
        public int presinto { get; set; }
        public int codigo { get; set; }
    }
```

con la clase tabla creo 3 lista

```
  List<tabla> lstSucursal = new List<tabla>();
  List<tabla> lstCentral = new List<tabla>();
  List<tabla> lstInsert = new List<tabla>();
```

La lista **lstSucursal** siempre tendra valores nuevos.

La lista **lstCentral** contendra valores existente en la tabla **lstSucursal**.

La lista **lstInsert** necesito almacenar aqui los valores que estan en **lstSucursal** pero no en **lstCentral**

```
lstSucursal.Add(new tabla() { presinto = 1,  codigo  = 12345678, });
lstSucursal.Add(new tabla() { presinto = 2,  codigo  = 12345678, });
lstSucursal.Add(new tabla() { presinto = 2,  codigo  = 74185296, });
lstSucursal.Add(new tabla() { presinto = 1,  codigo  = 74185296, });
lstSucursal.Add(new tabla() { presinto = 1,  codigo  = 03698521, });
lstSucursal.Add(new tabla() { presinto = 1,  codigo  = 01478963, });


 lstCentral.Add(new tabla() { presinto = 1,  codigo  = 12345678, });
 lstCentral.Add(new tabla() { presinto = 2,  codigo  = 12345678, });
 lstCentral.Add(new tabla() { presinto = 2,  codigo  = 74185296, });
 lstCentral.Add(new tabla() { presinto = 1,  codigo  = 74185296, });
```

Estoy intentando recorrer y comparar los valores para almacenarlos en la lista **lstInsert** que deberian ser los siguientes:

```
presinto = 1 codigo = 03698521
presinto = 1 codigo = 01478963
```

Estoy practicando con un foreach pero no me agrega a la lista **lstInsert** los valores que necesito

```
            foreach (var sucursal in lstSucursal)
            {
                foreach (var central in lstCentral)
                {
                    if (sucursal.codigo != central.codigo )
                    {
                        if (sucursal.presinto != central.presinto )
                        {
                            lstInsert.Add(sucursal);
                        }
                    }
                   break;
                }
            }
```

De que manera puedo validar para insertar con los valores que necesito

Comment: Necesitas los elementos que están en el arreglo A, pero no están en el arreglo B? Qué tal [`.Except()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-6.0)?

Comment: Si correcto, ya utilice el metodo .Except() sin resultado alguno

Comment: Fue lo mismo que tu comentario, pero la respuesta de Yussef agregaba mas sintaxis para poder tener el resultado

Comment: Es decir, Yussef te hizo la tarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1.- Usando Except con Override a Equals y GetHashCode***

Puedes ocupar Except si haces override a los métodos Equals y GetHashCode

```
public class tabla
{
    public int presinto { get; set; }
    public int codigo { get; set; }
    
    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        if(obj == null || obj.GetType() != typeof(tabla)) return false;
        var tabla2 = (tabla)obj;
        return tabla2.presinto == presinto && tabla2.codigo == codigo;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return presinto ^ codigo;
    }
}
```

```
var lstInsert = lstSucursal.Except(lstCentral);
```

***2.- Usando Except cambiando la de class a record***

Si ocupas un redord en vez de una clase no necesitas realizar más cambios. (Tambien funciona con struct)

```
public record tabla  //o public struct tabla
{
    public int presinto { get; set; }
    public int codigo { get; set; }
}
```

```
var lstInsert = lstSucursal.Except(lstCentral);
```

***3.- Usando Linq***

```
var lstInsert = from a in lstSucursal
                from b in lstCentral
                where a.codigo != b.codigo && a.presinto != b.presinto
                select a;
```

Comment: Gracias @Yussef funciono de las 2 maneras.